# Twitter client for OSX that posts via proxy?

Tags: twitter

I am looking for a Twitter client for OS X, which does not directly connect to Twitter.

I mean something like Hootsuite, brought to Desktop.

And why I want this? Because Twitter is blocked in my country, and I want a client acts like a proxy by connecting to their own service, and their own servers connect to Twitter.

PS:

- Hola does not work. I think it's blocked too (maybe I am wrong).
- Tor works, but it is too slow. It takes ages to load the first page of Twitter. I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Upvote because "blocked in my country" makes me want to see you get a solution to this.

Comment: A VPN (or Tor) might be the better solution in this case though

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Spotflux](http://www.spotflux.com/). It runs on system level which means you can use Twitter for OS X and other apps without having to install additional plugins in browsers.

There are also other paid alternatives like [TunnelBear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/) or [NetShade](http://raynersoftware.com/netshade/). I personally use NetShade because it doesn’t require Java like Spotflux.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you can use [Hola](https://hola.org/) as a free VPN and simulate you're in an other (selectable) country. Works great, installable as plugin in firefox and google chrome.